# Facebook React: Invariant Violation and elements than didn't mount automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning Facebook React by doing a small example.
I decided check if my knowledge about the `this` binding was ok so I created three `React.class` where the mutable states are in the parent and the middle only pass the callbacks to the children to manipulate it.

Basic structure:

```
- MainFrame (states here)
  - FriendBox (only pass the callbacks for change states to Friend)
    -Friend
```

Notice than I could use `transferThisProp` but actually I preferred made this "manually".

FriendBox render contains this:

```
var allFriends = this.props.friends.map((function (f) {
  return(
    <Friend key = {f.id}
            name = {f.name}
            select = {this.props.select}
    />
  )
}).bind(this))
```

Friend render contains this:

```
return(
  <div className="friend">
    {this.props.name}
    <a href="" onClick={this.props.select(this.props.key)}>
      select
    </a>
  </div>
)
```

When running my code I get the following message:

```
MainFrame.sendToFriendH:
  Invariant Violation: receiveComponent(...):
  Can only update a mounted component. react.js:7276
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation:
  receiveComponent(...): Can only update a mounted component.
```

The interesting part is that when using the react extension for chrome I can check that the virtual `DOM` is well and the bindings are ok. Everything looks fine except than the Child component for the first `Friend` element says `_lifeCycleState: "UNMOUNTED"`

This made me think than I am doing a mistake where the bottom child is not being rendered and mounted.
All the code fails but I don't know exactly why.
Can anyone can tell me why the element is not automatically mounted and how can I fix it?

Full Code: http://jsfiddle.net/RvjeQ/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you write

```
onClick={this.props.select(this.props.key)}
```

you're calling the `this.props.select` handler immediately and setting its *result* as the onClick handler. I'm guessing you want to instead do a partial application, which you can do using an arrow function:

```
onClick={(e) => this.props.select.bind(this.props.key, e)}
```

If you don't care about the event arg, you can skip it.

You can also use `.bind()` like so:

```
onClick={this.props.select.bind(null, this.props.key)}
```

Comment: thank so much for the reply Ben, I still need learn a lot of javascript :D ... this works like a charm (after fix other mistake than I did in the code :D) thanks!!...

Comment: Got caught out by this one too. Great fix.

Comment: or `onClick={() => select(key)}` if you're using es6 and have destructed those variables

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, you don't have to do

```
this.props.friends.map((function(){ ... }).bind(this));
```

The second argument to [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) allows you to set the context for the callback function. Use this instead

```
this.props.friends.map(function(f){ ... }, this);
```

You could also use an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that has lexical scope

```
this.props.friends.map(f =>
  <Friend key = {f.id}
          name = {f.name}
          select = {this.props.select}
  />
)
```

---

Also, when you're working with complex props, you can do things like

```jsx
var props = {
  key:    f.id,
  name:   f.name,
  select: this.props.select
};

<Friend {...props} />
```